# curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer on flask_restful on AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, curl, flask, flask-restful

```
*   Trying x.x.x.x...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to x.x.x.x (x.x.x.x) port 443 (#0)
> GET /sents HTTP/1.1
> Host: x.x.x.x:443
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 1
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

^^ Port 80 works fine, 443 and any other port fails. I've tried using flask_sslify on the app, but it fails anyways (the redirect comes out for port 80 though)

ufw status shows 443 as open / lsof shows the app as listening

Not sure if it's a AWS-specific problem, everything works fine on my local machine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `iptables` issue maybe?

Comment: @Busturdust oops forgot to mention, i've checked iptables as well..

Comment: There may also be another ACL specific to AWS I am not so sure with AWS. This may give some guidance http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html